# Blend 4 Xaml Parse Exception (Line: 0 Position: 0) problems

Tags: silverlight, xaml, blend

i have problems with my Blend project. When i open it i can see the Design windows with the graphics.

But when i try to manipulate the forms in the design windows, the following error appear:

> XamlParse Exception (Line: 0 Position: 0)
>   StackTrace
>   à MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
>   à MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size avaibleSize)
>   à System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride (Size avaibleSize)
>   à System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride (IntPtr native Target, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single&outWidth, Single&outHeight)
>   InnerException: None

[image]

I really dont understand the problem because when i run the project (F5), everything works !

Once the project has been run, the error stay and i cant manipulate the forms inside the design window.

Does somebody has ever had this problem ?

```
<UserControl xmlns:sdk="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"; 
             x:Class="Casting.MainPage" 
             xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"; 
             xmlns:x="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"; 
             xmlns:d="schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"; 
             xmlns:tk="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"; 
             xmlns:layoutToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolki‌​t"               
             xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows" 
             xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
             xmlns:util="clr-namespace:Casting.Util;assembly=Casting.Util" 
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
             xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL4"
             xmlns:layoutToolkitPrimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.La‌​yout.Toolkit" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="800" 
             d:DesignWidth="1280" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Casting" 
             DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
             >
```

Comment: Have you used an invalid measurement (width or height) somewhere in your XAML?

Comment: @Kevin - i have taken your XAML and added it to your question - where did those semi colons come from? This is incomplete - do you add those? Do you have some more XAML to add? (If so just edit your question and add it).